# Regex to get paragraph between the same word

Tags: javascript, regex

I got the text file like this

```
...
(Some text to introduce the list)
...

UserInfo
  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
  OtherItem:"123"
UserInfo
  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
  OtherItemA:"123"
  OtherItemB:"123"
UserInfo
  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
  OtherItemA:"123"
  OtherItemB:"123"
   -OtherSubItemC:"123"
    -OtherSubItemD:"123"
UserInfo
  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
UserInfo
  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
...
...
...
```

This is the list which storing the user information in **Text File**

Now my task is parse these data into json or csv file, which can process by program and show the user in table.

My solution is using javascript to do:

```
fetch("./list.txt").then(async i=>{
    window.myString = await i.text() // get string by text
    list = myString.match(/"(.*)"/g)
})
```

Now, I can get the array like this:

```
["user","user@example.com"......]
```

And I found that not all users have the same counts of information. so I cannot just split the array to become the user array.

But fortunately, Each user have **UserInfo** before the paragraph and **UserInfo** in other place.

So I have an idea, which is using regex or other function to **get the text between UserInfo** like:

```
[
'  User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
  OtherItem:"123"',

'User:"user"
  Email:"user@example.com"
  Phone:"12341234"
  OtherItemA:"123"
  OtherItemB:"123"',
]
```

And I will loop the item's line to create the object.

But I don't know to get the paragraph using regex.

I tried something like `/UserInfo(.*)UserInfo/g` but they all failed to match.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `/UserInfo([^]*?)(?=UserInfo)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/^UserInfo(?:\n[ \t].*)*/gm
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fpr9gX/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  UserInfo                 'UserInfo'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
(?<=UserInfo)(\s*^.*\n*)*?(?=UserInfo)
```

It gets everything but the last entry. This can be fixed by adding a final "UserInfo" in that list. Note that this solution does *not* include UserInfo as part of the text match.